# Spring Boot Application deployed on Elastic Beanstalk Java environment returns 502

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, spring-boot, port, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy a very simple Spring Boot application on AWS Elastic Beanstalk using AWS's Java configuration (not their Tomcat configuration), but I keep getting a 502 error with the following log:

```
2016/06/10 02:00:14 [error] 4921#0: *1 connect() failed 
(111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 38.94.153.178,   
server: , request: "GET /test HTTP/1.1", upstream:   "http://127.0.0.1:5000/test",
host: "my-single-instance-java-app.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com"
```

I've tried setting my port via Spring's application.properties to what the log seems to want (5000, using `server.port=5000`) and have verified that my application runs successfully on that port on localhost.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34619548/beanstalk-502-bad-gateway-spring-application) is very similar, except that I'm deploying a JAR instead of a WAR. It seems like there is something I'm missing regarding configuring Nginx, and I don't know how to proceed.

Here's my Spring Application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }

    @RestController
    public static class MainController {

        @RequestMapping("/test")
        public String testMethod() {
            return "Method success!";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste your security group rules?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're asking for but I have two roles: 
role: aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role
permissions:
AWSElasticBeanstalkWebTier 
AWSElasticBeanstalkMulticontainerDocker AWSElasticBeanstalkWorkerTier

role: aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role
permissions:
AWSElasticBeanstalkEnhancedHealth
AWSElasticBeanstalkService

Comment: No this are roles I wanted the Security Group for your EC2 instances .

Comment: I'm still not quite sure if this is what you're asking for http://imgur.com/a/RwXgk

Comment: Ok Add a security rule in Inbound for TCP Port 5000 "0.0.0.0/32"

Comment: That works! Can you explain what was going wrong that was fixed with this change?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Nginx doesn't know on which port your spring boot applicaiton is running.
Make application run on port 5000 that Nginx redirects to by default by adding "server.port=5000" to application.properties or other suggested ways in the last step:

https://pragmaticintegrator.wordpress.com/2016/07/12/run-your-spring-boot-application-on-aws-using-elastic-beanstalk/

Comment: My spring boot app is running on default port I opened up security group still same issue (Bad Gateway)

Answer (score 7):

From your question description and the security group settings you send me your only inbound Port 80 for your EC2 instance was open to world through firewall and you were using port 5000 for your application. So using the security rule that I gave you it opened the inbound port 5000 too for your EC2 instance so your application started working without above error.

Comment: Isn't the traffic supposed to come into the server through port 80 and `nginx` forwards the traffic to the embedded application server on port 5000? It seems like you wouldn't want to expose port 5000. I wonder if this would work if you added a rule for port 5000 with "127.0.0.1/0". There is no mention of this on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/security-group-rules-reference.html

Answer (score 1):

If somebody is still getting such error, after setting server.port=5000.
Here's what you can do if you got db connectivity:

1. In configuration section of your dashboard, go to RDS section and create a remote db. Remember username, password of formed db.
2. In Software section, add following properties:

SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://(your-db-url)/ebdb

SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=(username)

SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=(password)

SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO=update

SPRING_JPA_DATABASE_PLATFORM=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

Answer (score 1):

After reading both eb-engine.log as well nginx/error.log, the default nginx port is 5000 whereas the default port for spring-boot is 8080.

We can update our application via the elastic beanstalk CLI with the [setenv](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-setenv.html) cmd.

```
eb setenv SERVER_PORT=5000
```

We can update this in the code via application.properties

```
server.port=5000
```

Answer (score 1):

These steps worked for me,

1. Go-To > Environments > Select your environment,
2. Select "Configuration" at the left
3. Click on "Edit" against Software
4. Scroll Down to "Environment Properties"
5. add one more entry SERVER_PORT and set some number, I set 5000

[image]