# Spring Boot on AWS Beanstalk throwing 404

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I was about to host my spring boot backend on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Cause this is the first time doing so, I followed this [tutorial](https://pragmaticintegrator.wordpress.com/2016/07/12/run-your-spring-boot-application-on-aws-using-elastic-beanstalk/).

In short: I configured and used *awsebcli* to initialize and deploy. This went well so far. At the end of the tutorial, the guy meant I should switch the *server.port* in my Spring Boot App to *5000* which I did.

I checked all the logs and made sure the application started well, Tomcat listens on Port 5000 also. But I still have this annoying 404 in my access.log of the nginx.

```
[12/Dec/2017:16:13:08 +0000] "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/1.0" "-"
```

Healthcheck also means "Severe". And there's no way to access the by EB provided url via Postman. I checked also if I can specify the port directly *ulr:5000/health*

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755765/spring-boot-application-deployed-on-elastic-beanstalk-java-environment-returns-5) post mentions creating an Inbound rule for port 5000. I did that too but nothing changed.

Can someone give me a hint? I suspect that something's wrong with these security groups. [image: I even added port 8080 to test the whole thing]

Comment: Is nginx configured to pass `/health` to your application?  Does your application have a `/health` path defined?  How is the health check configured in Beanstalk?  Go to `All Applications -> Your Environment -> Configuration -> Load Balancing` and check the "Application health check URL".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a dumb mistake by me. Everything is well configured but the basepath for everything is /api/* and this caused my /health check to fail with (of course) a 404.

Thanks to you @stdunbar for your help. It made me crosscheck all apis again.