# Deploying Spring Boot app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk — getting 502 error

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, tomcat, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I know, there are a lot of such quesions and answers here, but none of them helped me. I try to install my simple Spring Boot app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. There is a limitation: it must use `.jsp` templates, so it's `.war`, not `.jar`. If I use predefined Tomcat env on Elastic Beanstalk, everything works fine, but my goal is to use Java env.

When I install my app, its status is getting `Degraded` and I become 502 when trying to reach the url.

Locally everything works perfect.

I changed port in `application.properties` to 5000, but it didn't help. I found a recommendation to use a security rule for inbound for `TCP Port 5000 "0.0.0.0/32"` but it didn't help eather.

Here are my `pom.xml` dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
            <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
            <version>4.6.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

application.properties:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/view/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
server.port=5000
```

Main Java class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemowebApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(DemowebApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemowebApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

AWS error logs:

```
2019/05/07 21:04:45 [error] 7827#0: *19 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 91.232.158.8, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "my-endpoint-tst.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com"
2019/05/07 21:04:46 [error] 7827#0: *19 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 91.232.158.8, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/favicon.ico", host: "my-endpoint-tst.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com", referrer: "my-endpoint-tst.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/"
```

I suspect that problem is with my Tomcat configuration, but all my experiments with it didn't help yet.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755765/spring-boot-application-deployed-on-elastic-beanstalk-java-environment-returns-5?rq=1

Comment: It might be an issue with your Security Group. Please open your inbound rule for port 5000.

Comment: Yes I saw that recommendation and did it but id didn't help: `Custom TCP Rule
TCP
5000
0.0.0.0/32`

Comment: Can you please select HTTP 80 0.0.0.0/0 and ::/0 and try it.

Comment: It didn't help(

Comment: https://pragmaticintegrator.wordpress.com/2016/07/12/run-your-spring-boot-application-on-aws-using-elastic-beanstalk/

Comment: Here are my security rules: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/4010679/485e209757196650e4e090fec7659541

Comment: About your linke above — I read it and, as I wrote, made my app running on port 5000. Didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with this. I would load the JAR up to Elastic Beanstalk and when I would try to access the URL, I would get the 502 Apache error with the degraded status. Locally, I was set to port 8080 but when I tried to access it through my URL I was getting the 502. My problem was:

1) I was not exporting and uploading the fat .JAR file from my IDE when I was exporting it. I know you said you cant use .JAR but just make sure when you are exporting your project, you are also exporting all the dependencies from Maven with it.

2) This might be a bigger help than the first part of this answer but even when I was putting my port in the application.properties, it wasn't pulling through to the Elastic Beanstalk instance. What I successfully ended up doing to solve this issue was going into the management console in AWS, going to my Beanstalk instance, and going to the configuration tab.

On the configuration tab there is a section Software and in that subsection, go to the Environment Properties. In the Name section of the environment properties, enter `SERVER_PORT` and for the value section, enter `5000`. Click apply and let the instance restart.